# how to render multiple copies of this component in react jsx

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I want to create another copy of this component function and each time a new copy is created i want to change the `<h3>` and `<p>` tag

```
function Ads(product) {
    return(
      <div className = "row" id="user-ads">
        <div className = "col-sm-6 col-md-5">
          <div className = "thumbnail">
            <img src = "img/img1.jpg" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail" />
          </div>
          <div className = "caption">
            <div className="border">
              <h3>{product.title}</h3>
              <p>{product.desc}</p>  
              <button className = "btn btn-primary" role = "button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-detail">View Details
              </button>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Ads title="PlayStation 4" desc="Lorem ipsum jipsum Lorem ipsum jipsum"/>, document.getElementById('ads'));
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. How do you want to change the tags? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var configObjects = [
  {
    desc: "Lorem ipsum jipsum Lorem ipsum jipsum",
    img: "img1.jpg",
    title: "PlayStation 4"
  },
  {
    desc: "Lorem ipsum jipsum Lorem ipsum jipsum",
    img: "img2.jpg",
    title: "PlayStation 5"
  },
  {
    desc: "Lorem ipsum jipsum Lorem ipsum jipsum",
    img: "img3.jpg",
    title: "PlayStation 6"
  }
]

function Ads() {
  var multipleAds = AdsAssembly(configObjects);
  return(
    <div>{multipleAds}</div>  
  );
}

function AdsAssembly(array) {
  var jsxArray = [];
  array.forEach(function (adObject, index) {
    jsxArray.push(AdsContent(adObject));
  })
  return jsxArray;
}

function AdsContent(object) {
  return (
    <div className = "row" id="user-ads">
      <div className = "col-sm-6 col-md-5">
        <div className = "thumbnail">
          <img src ={"img/" + object.img} alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail" />
        </div>
        <div className = "caption">
          <div className="border">
            <h3>{object.title}</h3>
            <p>{object.desc}</p>  
            <button className = "btn btn-primary" role = "button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-detail">View Details
            </button>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Ads/>, document.getElementById('ads'));
```

You can use the configuration array to dynamically populate each ad you would like to display. Cheers!

Alternatively you could pass the configs as a property like so:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Ads configs={configObjects} />, document.getElementById('ads'));
```

Then use them like this:

```
function Ads(props) {
      var multipleAds = AdsAssembly(props.configs);
      return(
        <div>{multipleAds}</div>  
      );
    }
```